# mkdir returns The syntax of the command is incorrect on windows

Tags: windows, directory, mkdir

mkdir is unable to create direcotry

mkdir path/to/dir
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use back slashes, like this:
mkdir path\to\dir

Comment: Windows being windows again

Comment: Alternatively you can wrap the path in quotes, `mkdir "/path/to/dir"`

Answer (score 0):

Write folder name with command.
For example we want to create folder with name of "dummy_folder" then we have to command `mkdir dummy_folder`